# Drop ball down screen at location of touch,

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Xcode and I am making an app that lets you drop a ball and hit blocks on the bottom. So far I am able to get the ball to drop when I touch anywhere on the screen however it only drops from the middle (probably because I have `BALL.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height)`. how would I be able to get the ball to drop from the exact location of where I touch on the screen. Thank you!

also to get the ball to drop I used

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
```

Thanks again

Comment: touches is a set of touches. Each touch has a locationInView. Take a look at the docs for UITouch. You will find your answer there.

Comment: thank you. i will check that out.